# removeLayer or removeFrom(map) not working on betterwms layer from leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, layers, html5

I have this HTML checkbox:

```
<li>
 <input type="checkbox" id="bairroCENTRO-checkbox">
 <label for="bairroCENTRO-checkbox">Bairro</label>
</li>
```

And this JS code that, whenever the checkbox changes, it adds (using a betterWMS request) or removes the layer:

```
function bairroCheckbox(nomeBairro) {
    var nome_bairro = "bairro" + nomeBairro + "-checkbox";

    function requestBairro(bairro) {
        return new L.tileLayer.betterWms(url_geoserver, {
            layers: 'bdgeo:bairro',
            transparency: 'true',
            format: 'image/svg',
            opacity: 1,
            maxZoom: 20,
            attribution: "Geo Portal",
            CQL_FILTER: "nome in ('" + bairro + "')",
            zIndex: 2000
        });
    }

    document.getElementById(nome_bairro).addEventListener('change', function () {
        console.log('Checkbox changed');
        var camadabairro = requestBairro(nomeBairro);

        if (this.checked) {
            camadabairro.addTo(map);
            console.log('Layer added to the map');
        } else {
            map.removeLayer(camadabairro);
            console.log('Layer removed from the map');
        }
    });
}

bairroCheckbox(bairro);
```

However, it's not removing the layer. As you can see below, the checkbox is not checked, but the layer is still there.

[image: Layer not being removed]

I already tested removing using .removeFrom(map), but had no success, and the web page doesn't show any error.

Unfortunately, I can't provide the URL of the GeoServer. What is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. You might want to add debug statements to print the console log, then report the log contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your code is that with `var camadabairro = requestBairro(nomeBairro);` you create a new layer every time check box is checked/unchecked.

Solution is to put `camadabairro` layer variable at the global level and then create layer only the first time that check box is checked.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var camadabairro = null;

function bairroCheckbox(nomeBairro) {
  var nome_bairro = "bairro" + nomeBairro + "-checkbox";

  function requestBairro(bairro) {
    return new L.tileLayer.betterWms(url_geoserver, {
      layers: 'bdgeo:bairro',
      transparency: 'true',
      format: 'image/svg',
      opacity: 1,
      maxZoom: 20,
      attribution: "Geo Portal",
      CQL_FILTER: "nome in ('" + bairro + "')",
      zIndex: 2000
    });
  }

  document.getElementById(nome_bairro).addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (!camadabairro) {
      camadabairro = requestBairro(nomeBairro);
    }

    if (this.checked) {
      camadabairro.addTo(map);
    } else {
      map.removeLayer(camadabairro);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: IT WORKED!!! Thank you my friend :D thank you so much.